# Visual Foxpro Database Stored Procedure with Oledb Provider

Tags: stored-procedures, visual-foxpro

I am using Visual Foxpro 8.0 database. Below procedure I am using to return records from database on basis of condition matching but it raised error that:

> "Function is not implemented."

Foxpro Procedure ------------------------

```
PROCEDURE FX_Proc_ValidateUser (paramUserName AS Character, paramPassword AS Character)
LOCAL VarUserName AS Character, varXml
VarUserName = IIF(VARTYPE(paramUserName)!="N","",paramUserName)
LOCAL VarPassword AS Character
VarPassword = IIF(VARTYPE(paramPassword)!="N","",paramPassword)
SELECT userinfoid, ;
        username, ;
        password ;
FROM tm_userinfo.dbf ;
WHERE username = VarUserName AND password = VarPassword ;
INTO CURSOR procResult  
varXml = ""
CURSORTOXML("procResult","varXml",1,32,0,"1")
RETURN varXml
ENDPROC
```

Front End code for calling this procedure------------------

```
string ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\Users\raj\Documents\Visual FoxPro Projects\dbFoxMaster.dbc;Collating Sequence=machine;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
OledbConnection objOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
objOleDbConnection.Open();
OleDbCommand objOleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand();
objOleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
objOleDbCommand.CommandText = "FX_Proc_ValidateUser";
objOleDbCommand.Connection = objOleDbConnection;
objOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("paramUserName", OleDbType.Char).Value = "abc";
objOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("paramPassword", OleDbType.Char).Value = "123";
var xmlString = oOleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();

        // creating a dataset from the xml 
        dataSet.ReadXml(reader);
        table = dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```

How to get resultset from foxpro 8.0 stored procedure using OledbCommand?

Comment: Maybe this link helps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299820

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is that you are putting your results into an array and only the first item in the array is being returned.  You should change the stored procedure so that it uses a cursor.

VFP9 Example

Here is a stored procedure example from the northwind.dbc:
[image]

Here is an example of calling the stored procedure using C#:

```
var northwindDbcPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9\Samples\Northwind\Northwind.dbc";
var connectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + northwindDbcPath;
var table = new DataTable();

using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "CustOrdersDetail";
        command.Parameters.Add("x", 10248);

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

        adapter.Fill(table);
    }
}
```

VFP8 Example:
(I don't have a copy of VFP8 but I believe that this will work)
[image]

```
var northwindDbcPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9\Samples\Northwind\Northwind.dbc";
var connectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + northwindDbcPath;
DataTable table;

using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "CustOrdersDetail2";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("x", 10248);

        connection.Open();      
        // executing stored procedure and getting xml result
        var xml = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;

        connection.Close();

        using(var reader = new StringReader(xml)) {
            var dataSet = new DataSet();

            // creating a dataset from the xml 
            dataSet.ReadXml(reader);
            table = dataSet.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom Brothers, This procedure is meaningfull but I am using Visual Foxpro 8.0 so here SETRESULTSET() doesn't support. when I accessed procedure with Oledb Provider then it raised  error that "File 'setresultset.prg' does not exist". Please suggest me It's urgent.

Comment: Thanks Tom Brothers for making these efforts, but by using your new procedure and its consuming style I am getting a new exception that "Function is not implemented" while debugging line command.ExecuteScalar().

Comment: Dear Tom Brothers, error comes in .net code while i execute command. var xml = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;

Comment: I installed VFP8 and tested my code.  It worked as expected.  Can you post your stored procedure code?

Comment: Hi Tom Brothers, I have edited question and you can see what I am writing in Stored Procedure and how executing this from .net

Comment: Hi Tom Brothers, I have edited question and you can see what I am writing in Stored Procedure and how executing this from .net.  var xmlString = oOleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();  line raises error that  "Function is not implemented"

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting that error message.  The code that you posted is working as expected for me (with fixing some minor typos on the .net side).  Although, there is one thing I need to point out... you probably want to change your VARTYPE checking to test against != "C" instead of != "N" otherwise your character parameter values will not get passed to the query.  Do you have the latest VfpOleDb driver installed?

Comment: Tom I also checked for != "N" in place of != "C" still I got same error. Ok thank you for supporting me... If it's possible then please tell me some best foxpro practice link so that I can understand well or if you have any ebook so please mail me on shoebmca@gmail.com Thanks again Tom...

Comment: Here is a good resource for VFP books:  http://www.hentzenwerke.com/catalog/zcatalog.htm#20

Answer (score 0):

I have no VFP around and the last time I used VFP it was still version 3.0...

I would try something like this based on the specs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa978148%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). To learn the rest read-up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975325%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
PROCEDURE insertData (pusername, ppassword)

                    SELECT userinfoid, username, password 
                    FROM tm_userinfo.dbf 
                    WHERE username = pusername AND password = ppassword
                    INTO ARRAY results
     RETURN results
ENDPROC
```

Comment: Thanks rene to help, I used your procedure but it returns only unique key of record while I have to return resultset from database if condition matched. I have updated my Question please see again and help me.. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Rene, Please tell me how to get resultset from foxpro stored procedure using OledbCommand Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Visual Foxpro stored procedure is basically using Visual Foxpro code to perform tasks such as validating columns on insert or update or delete.

For Example, you might add the following code to VFP database stored procedure to validate a "State" column:

```
PROCEDURE ValidateState()
IF address.state <> [OH]
    MESSAGEBOX([Incorrect State value!], 48, [Invalid State])
ENDIF
ENDPROC
```

For querying a table in a Foxpro database, you may want to look at creating local views. You can do this by right clicking inside the foxpro database and selecting "New Local View", then define your view using the query builder. In the Filter tab, under the "Example" column, you can define parameters using the "?" such as "?pusername".

Here is how you would call the view from your Foxpro code:

```
 LOCAL pusername AS Integer   
 pusername = "SomeUserName"    &&Use this to filter the view
 SELECT 0
 USE MyViewName       &&This will call the view and perform the filter.
```

You can also make these views updatable and perform your inserts against the view.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I am facing problem in getting resultset from foxpro database. Please see my updated question...and help me.